# Media query is not applied on device rotation

Tags: css, media-queries

I have adapted my website for the following resolutions, and those are my media queries.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 320px)" href="css/320/main320.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 360px)" href="css/360/main360.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 480px)" href="css/480/main480.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 640px)" href="css/640/main640.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)" href="css/768/main768.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 960px)" href="css/main.css"/>
```

As far as I understand this is the right way to adapt the website for most devices instead of trying to target each individual device which is impractical.
When I test this code with the google chrome development tools it works perfectly, but when I test it on a real phone I get a weird behavior.

I have been able to test this on iPhone 4 and iPhone 6, on both of them the screen min width only works in portrait mode, when i rotate them it doesn't update even if i refresh the page.

I have also been able to test it on a few android phones including galaxy 5,6 and LG g4, on those devices the style doesn't change on screen rotation but if I refresh the page on landscape it updates to the right settings.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Because orientation is not taken into account when executing media queries. You should add `(orientation: portrait)` and `(orientation: landscape)` to your queries.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  media="only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: landscape)" 
  href="css/640/main640.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `device-width` is still withing the same boundaries in `landscape` and `protrait`, have you tried:

```
and (orientation: landscape)
```

I know it adds more work, but I ran into this also and had to be more specific in terms of the `queries`